# List under list to convert into json data in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, list

This is my controller method-

```
 public ActionResult GetTopPaymentWiseCustomer(int? recordNumber, DateTime? spnStartDate, DateTime? spnEndDate)
    {
        var data = _commonService.GetTopPaymentWiseCustomer(recordNumber, spnStartDate, spnEndDate);
        Dictionary<GrantChartViewModel, List<GrantChartDetailsViewModel>> chartData = new Dictionary<GrantChartViewModel, List<GrantChartDetailsViewModel>>();

        if (data != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                var details = data.Where(o => o.CustomerId == item.CustomerId);
                var cl = new GrantChartViewModel
                {
                    Category = item.RangeName
                };
                List<GrantChartDetailsViewModel> detailsList = new List<GrantChartDetailsViewModel>();
                if (details != null)
                {
                    foreach (var dl in details)
                    {
                        var d = new GrantChartDetailsViewModel
                        {
                            start = dl.Start,
                            duration = dl.Duration,
                            color = dl.ColorCode,
                            task = dl.TotalPayment.ToString() + "%"
                        };
                        detailsList.Add(d);
                    }
                }

                chartData.Add(cl, detailsList);
            }
        }

        return Json(chartData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And this are my models.. Which need to convert into json like (to plot in amChart (grant chart))-

```
  var ganttData = [{
                category: "Customer 1", segments: [
                    { start: 0, duration: 10, color: "#727d6f", task: "40%" },
                    { start: 20, duration: 10, color: "#8dc49f", task: "60%" },
                ]
            }, {
                category: "Customer 2", segments: [
                    { start: 15, duration: 10, color: "#727d6f", task: "70%" },
                    { start: 50, duration: 10, color: "#8dc49f", task: "80%" },
                ]
            }];
```

For a single object(GrantChartViewModel), there will be a list of object (GrantChartDetailsViewModel)

```
 public class GrantChartViewModel
{
    public GrantChartViewModel()
    {
        listGrantChartDetails = new List<GrantChartDetailsViewModel>();
    }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public List<GrantChartDetailsViewModel> listGrantChartDetails { get; set; }

}


public class GrantChartDetailsViewModel
{
    public int start { get; set; }
    public int duration { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string task { get; set; }
}
```

I tried with dictionary but it didn't came out. Any suggestion?

Comment: Dictionaries don't play well with Serialization, I found that out the hard way. I did find that you can use Lists of KeyValuePairs, but that is another thing altogether. When doing serialization I have found making custom class objects, and then a custom class object which contains a list of those custom objects is the easy way to go when it comes to JSON and serialization.

Comment: can you suggest me link? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is it you want a link for? I am still kind of unclear as to what you are asking help for? Are you having trouble serializing data and passing it from your controller to the view, or from your view to the controller?

Comment: i want to convert  list under list into json data (like ganttData)..  Any way thanks for trying.

Comment: What does the JSON look like with the code you have?

Comment: @Sohel Rana Please answer whether you are trying to convert data on the server side or client side, if you are needing help converting on the server side, your models should work fine. You would just need to create an instance of class GrantChartViewModel, and populate its list of model type GrantChartDetailsViewModel. Once you have done that, I recommend using System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer to serialize your class object and return it to your view.

Comment: @Sohel Rana if you are having trouble passing your JSON object in your javascript example above to your controller(server), your server side method would need to accept a list of class type GrantChartViewModel

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show an a valid, well-formed example of the JSON you want to generate -- i.e. something that passes validation at https://jsonlint.com/?  Your `var ganttData = ...` string isn't actually JSON. Also, what version of asp.net-mvc are you using?  Different versions use different JSON serializers as explained in [Json serializers in ASP.NET and other](https://techblog.dorogin.com/json-serializers-in-asp-net-and-other-e12d3d62933f).

Comment: Thanks all i got the solution.